# C++ Builder. Редактирование свойств формы

Tags: c++, delphi, form

Всем доброго дня! Работаю в C++ builder 10 и создаю *пустую* форму, которая по-умолчанию наследуется от класса **TForm**. Столкнулся с проблемой, корень которой лежит в свойствах, которые описывают форму:

[image: Свойства формы]

*В данном случае форма описывается на языке Delphi в файле .dfm, но пишу я на C++.*

Все свойства ( Left, Top, Caption....) подгружаются по-умолчанию при создании для описания формы.

Просматривая форму как текст (прик. картинка), я удаляю свойтва **ClientHeight** и **ClientWidth** (они не нужны мне для сохранения), но при компиляции они воскресают и снова занимают свои положенные места!

Мне не нужно, чтобы подчеркнутые выше свойства не сохранялись в *.dfm файле, описывающем форму.

Меня интересует вопрос: можно ли как-то их убрать данные атрибуты из сохраняемых свойств (сделать stored=false)?

Comment: Это обязательные свойства формы. Ширина и высота ведь должны быть какие-то в любом случае. Для чего их удалять из dfm?

Comment: @Максим - а с какой целью это хочется сделать? или на самом деле Вы хотите скрыть другие свойства (например, поле с паролем), но решили поменять вопрос, что бы было как то незаметно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClientWidth и ClientHeight это ширина и высота формы без учёта бордюров и заголовка окна, сохраняются автоматом. Ничего не поделаешь. Свойства Windth и Height вычисляются из этих переменных.